# How to get the pojo class object say Employee in controller class using spring 4 annotation

Tags: spring-mvc

How can i get the pojo class object say Employee in controller class using spring 4 annotation and which annotation is used to get the form parameter in controller class?

I am new in spring and just started to learn.

Please suggest the best site/tutorial to learn spring so that i can have handson on it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: To get the value of a form parameter, you'll be using the `@RequestParam` annotation.  As @IropOhek mentioned, you'll be using the `@ModelAttribute` annotation for the backing bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I clearly understood your question, pass the object to the Controller using the  `@ModelAttribute` annotation:

```
public class Controller {

   @ModelAttribute("employee")
   public Employee getEmployeel() {
     return new Employee();
   }

   @RequestMapping ("/index")
   public void index(@ModelAttribute ("employee") Employee employee, Model model) {
     //some logic
   }
}
```

To get the object from the Spring form, use `@ModelAttribute` too.

You can try the well-rated ["Spring in Action" book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/161729120X). Also, if you feel comfortable with video lessons, you could try [Gontuseries](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCA3RaMnfSmJsvv3TraOdipg).